# C++ - ensuring full serial response

Tags: c++, c, windows, serial-port

I am trying to read a serial response from a hardware device. The string I read is long and I only need a portion of it. To get to portion of the string I want I use `std::string.substr(x,y);` . The problem I run into however is sometimes I get an exception error because the buffer I am reading from doesn't have y characters. Here is the code I use now to read values:

```
while(1)
{
char szBuff[50+1] = {0};
char wzBuff[14] = {"AT+CSQ\r"};

DWORD dZBytesRead = 0;
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;


if(!WriteFile(hSerial, wzBuff, 7, &dZBytesRead, NULL))
    std::cout << "Write error";

if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, 50, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
    std::cout << "Read Error";



std:: cout << szBuff;
std::string test = std::string(szBuff).substr(8,10);
std::cout << test;
Sleep(500);
```

I am issuing the command "AT+CSQ". This returns:

> N, N
>
> OK

It returns two integer values seperated by a comma followed by a new line, followed by "OK".

**My question is, how can I make sure I read all values from the serial port before grabbing a substring? From what I understand, the last character received should be a new line.**

Comment: Define "all values". Why are you expecting to receive a certain exact amount of data? What exactly is the data source? Is there any documentation about the communication protocol that you should be reading? (I strongly suspect there is.)

Comment: Edited. I am waiting for a new line basically.

Answer (score 1):

The interface of your `ReadFile` function seems to provide you with the number of bytes read. If you know the length that is expected, you should loop trying reading from the file (probably port descriptor) until the expected number of bytes is read.

If the length of the response is not known, you might have to read and check in the read buffer whether the separator token has been read or not (in this case your protocol seems to indicate that a new-line can be used to determine EOM --end of message)

If you can use other libraries, I would consider using `boost::asio` and the `read_until` functionality (or the equivalent in whatever libraries you are using). While the code to manage this is not rocket science, in most cases there is no point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Ok so when this call is run successfully it returns 23 bytes. This means the the element 22 in my szByuff should be '\n' right? So can I just check for this?

Comment: Depending on the definition of your protocol, it might or not be guaranteed that the `\n` is within the first 23 bits or where. I would loop through the array and verify whether any of the values is `\n`, if it is not, then reread (be sure not to overwrite the old yet unprocessed data) and verify whether the token is in the last read block... But seriously, if you don't know how to verify whether the last element in an array is a particular value, you need to consider starting with a basic tutorial/book on C++.

Comment: No I know how to do that, I was just asking if it is the proper way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ReadFile` to read a certain amount of bytes per cycle into your buffer. This buffer should be filled until `ReadFile` reads `0` bytes, you have reached your `\n` or `\r\n` characters, or filled your buffer to the max.

Once you have done this, there would be no need to `substr` your string and you can iterate through your character buffer.

For example,

```
while (awaitResponse) {
    ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, 50, &dwBytesRead, NULL);

    if (dwBytesRead != 0) {
        // move memory from szBuff to your class member (e.g. mySerialBuff)

    } else {
        // nothing to read
        if (buffCounter > 0) {
            // process buffer
        }
        else {
            // zero out all buffers
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not having to use substr.

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself in the last line, you know that the terminator for the response is a new line character. You need to read from the serial until you receive a new line somewhere in the input. Everything you received from the previous new line to the current new line is the response, with everything after the current new line is part of the next response. This is achieved by reading in a loop, handling each response as it is discovered:

```
char* myBigBuff;
int indexToBuff = 0;
int startNewLine = 0;

while (ReadFile(hSerial, myBigBuff + indexToBuff, 100, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
{
    if (strchr(myBigBuff, '\n') != NULL)
    {
        handleResponse(myBigBuff + startNewLine, indexToBuff + dwBytesRead);
        startNewLine = indexToBuff + dwBytesRead;
    }

    // Move forward in the buffer. This should be done cyclically
    indexToBuff += dwBytesRead; 
}
```

This is the basic idea. You should handle the left overs characters via any way you choose (cyclic buffer, simple copy to a temp array, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I modified @Eli Iser code to:

```
while (ReadFile(hSerial, myBigBuff + indexToBuff, 1, &dwBytesRead, NULL)) {
            if (strchr(myBigBuff, '-') != NULL || dwBytesRead < 1)
                break;
            // Move forward in the buffer. This should be done cyclically
            indexToBuff += dwBytesRead; 
        }
        if (indexToBuff != 0) {
            //Do whatever with the code, it received successfully.
        }
```